# Ternary expression in type that looks at a union as a whole

Tags: typescript

Here's an example of a TypeScript type:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null ? never : T 


type Test1 = NonNullable<string>; // string
type Test2 = NonNullable<string | null>; // still string!
```

The ternary operator is applied individually to each member of the `T` union.
Now, I'd like to create a type that looks at union `T` as a whole, like this:

```
type NonNullable2<T> = ...?


type Test1 = NonNullable<string>; // string
type Test2 = NonNullable<string | null>; // never, because the provided T (string|null) extends null.
```

So, if I provide any `T` that can be null, I want to get `never`. Any other type should return `T`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Tangential: [Since TS version `4.8`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing), the `NonNullable` utility type is now written as `type NonNullable<T> = T & {};`.

Comment: I agree that the linked question answers mine. However, I wasn’t able to find it, because I did not know that the thing I encountered has a name - Distributive Conditional Types. An information about that and a link to TS docs would be the right answer to my question

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74559534/ternary-expression-in-type-that-looks-at-a-union-as-a-whole?noredirect=1#comment131686702_74559534) @mnj Your question is still a duplicate, and now it exists and is searchable for others — and includes a link to the other question so that they can read the answer and learn the name also.